# Nested order_by in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have to implement Nested orderby using sequelize but its not working below is my code

This whole code is working for me but I need to add sorting for a column reported_by which is present in Ticket table by reported_user_id name.

Below given images shows the hierarchy of database

TicketAssignment Table
[image]

Ticket Table
[image]

User table
[image]

TicketAssignment Table - ticket_id(FK) -> Ticket Table - id(PK)

Ticket Table - reported_user_id(FK) -> User Table - id(PK)

```
[let query = req.body.q;
 let err, tickets;
 let whereObj = {};

 if (req.body.statusForTicket > 0) {
   whereObj.status = 3;
 } else {
   whereObj.status = { [Op.in]: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5] };
 }

 if (req.user.role_id == 9) {
   whereObj.suppport_company_id = req.user.company_id;
 } else {
   whereObj.engineer_user_id = req.user.id;
 }
 let whereObjInc = {};
 if (query.trim() != "") {
   whereObjInc.title = { [Op.like]: '%' + query.trim() + '%' };
 }

 if (req.body.date_from !== -1 && req.body.date_to !== -1) {
   if (req.body.date_from != "") {
     whereObjInc.createdAt = { [Op.gte]: req.body.date_from };
   }

   if (req.body.date_to != "") {
     whereObjInc.createdAt = { [Op.lte]: req.body.date_from };
   }

   if (req.body.date_to != "" && req.body.date_from != "") {
     whereObjInc.createdAt = { [Op.between]: [req.body.date_from, req.body.date_to] };
   }
 }

 if (req.body.is_archive !== -1) {
   whereObjInc.is_archive = req.body.is_archive;
 }

 let customOrder = [[order_by, order_by_ASC_DESC]];
 if (order_by == 'title') {
   customOrder = [[{ model: Ticket }, order_by, order_by_ASC_DESC]];
 }
 let orderByCondition = [[order_by, order_by_ASC_DESC]];

 if (order_by == 'company') {

   orderByCondition = [[{ model: Company, as: 'reported', }]];

   //orderByCondition = [[{ model: Company, as: 'reported' }, 'company_name', order_by_ASC_DESC]];
 }
 if (order_by == 'accountable') {
   orderByCondition = [[{ model: Company, as: 'accountable' }, 'company_name', order_by_ASC_DESC]];
 }
 if (order_by == 'reported_by') {   
   orderByCondition = [[{ model: Ticket},[{ model: User }, 'first_name', order_by_ASC_DESC]]];
 }
 let order_type = ['company', 'accountable', 'reported_by'];

 if (order_type.includes(order_by)) { 
   [err, tickets] = await to(TicketAssignment.findAll({
     where: whereObj,
     include: [{ model: Ticket, where: whereObjInc }],
     limit: limit,
     offset: offset,
     order: orderByCondition,
   }));  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try it from your self. Try it from your self.